# Troubles with cyrillic encoding in PHP MySQL site

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, cp1251

Have a problem with the cyrillic encoding 
cyrillic data from mysql displayed correct, but when I add some cyrillic text on the page I get someting like this **С‹РІР°Р°Р°РїРІ**

data in MySQl  - `utf8_general_ci`

php file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251'); 

mysql_query('SET NAMES cp1251');
```

Comment: Have you tried `charset=utf-8` in your header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding the text in utf-8, while your page in 1251.
So, set your editor into Windows-1251 when adding text

OR

change your headers from 1251 to utf-8

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Comment: "..So, set your editor into Windows-1251 when adding text"


oh! yes of course